# How to merge path in Eclipse package explorer hierarchical view

Tags: eclipse

I'm using eclipse in MacOS,and I set package explorer to hierarchical view

now,package look like this:

> **util**
>
> - org
>
>   - abc
>
>     - db
>
>       - sql
>
>         - Connection.java

but in win7,look like this:

> **util**
>
> - org.abc.db.sql
>
>   - Connection.java

they can auto merge empty package path

how can I merge empty package path in eclipse @ MacOS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open the little triangle menu on the top of the view and select filters. This will open a dialog window where you can configure several aspect of the view. One of them is "empty parent packages" which will hide those packages if it is enable.

Comment: filters - "empty parent packages" has been opened,I did not modify the default configuration

Comment: Are you using a older version of eclipse on the Mac?

Comment: thanks,x4u,I re-installed the eclipse, the problem disappears

Comment: Unfortunately this only seems to work for packages, not for resource folders